# C# ClosedXML How to dump collection of objects into relational table in .xlsx

Tags: c#, .net, excel, closedxml

How to dump in-memory POCO objects into .xls format datasheet, with ClosedXML libary?

.
I have a domain classes:

**Product.cs**

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string? LongDescription { get; set; }
    public string? TechnicalData { get; set; }
    public float? Weight { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Image> Images { get; set; }
}
```

**Image.cs**

```
public class Image
{
    public string url { get; set; }
}
```

And a service that recives a collections of products:

**Service.cs**

```
List<Product> products = service.GetProducts();
```

That code saves it to .xlsx, but how to create a second sheet that contain collection of all product's images with two columns: Product's Id and Image's Url similar to relational database:

```
workbook.AddWorksheet("products").FirstCell().InsertTable<Product>(products, false);
var i = workbook.AddWorksheet("images").FirstCell();
foreach (Product p in products)
{
    i.InsertTable<Image>(p.Images, false);
}
workbook.SaveAs("foo.xlsx");
```

What is best practise of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
foreach (Product p in products)
{
    i.InsertTable<Image>(p.Images, false);
}
```

with

```
i.InsertTable(products.SelectMany(p => p.Images), false);
```

But in order to protect your outputs (XLSX file) from changes in your domain models, it is better to declare dedicated classes (say, `ProductDto`, `ImageDto`), perform the mapping in code and then dump a collection of DTOs into XLSX using `InsertTable` or `InsertData`. This would require more coding, but would be cleaner from the point of separation of concerns, and would give you more control over the ordering of columns, their titles, etc.